# Using SIZEOF operator with indirect addressing mode in MASM

Tags: string, masm, addressing

I'm trying to get the size of a string that esi holds the address of the first byte.

```
mov ebx, SIZEOF [esi]
```

Why won't this run? For an error it gives me  error A2081: mi, for that line number.

Answer (score 1):

> Why won't this run?

The syntax for `SIZEOF` is:

```
  SIZEOF variable | type
```

This only works at assembly-time, not at run-time. And it's not translated into code. So you can't use it anywhere you want.

An example:

```
.data
string BYTE "Hello World", 0

.code
mov eax, SIZEOF string ;  the size will be translated into an immediate value
```

If you can't know in advance the length of that string, you need to call some function to get it.